# How to randomly select and open a notebook using CDFPlayer

Tags: random, cdfplayer, notebooks

I have a lesson notebook for a class I am teaching. I'd like to separate the lesson content and the practice problems. Students are using the CDFPlayer program, not *Mathematica*.

I created a button that will open a specific notebook…

```
Button[
  "open",
  NotebookOpen[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[ButtonNotebook[]], "sample.nb"}]]]
```

and this works fine in the CDFPlayer.

However, selecting a "random" question from a list of files doesn't. Something in my code doesn't work in the free player. (The same code works fine in *Mathematica*)

This is what I tried:

```
Button[
  "open",
  NotebookOpen[RandomChoice[FileNames[{"*.nb"}, {NotebookDirectory[ButtonNotebook[]]}]]]]
```

I'm wondering if someone could offer a suggestion?   I'd like a button that when clicked,  will open a notebook from a folder of practice problems, and work in the CDFPlayer.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

I see (and appreciate) the feedback that the free CDFPlayer is NOT able to open files.  So that answers my question...

Comment: You can't use free CDF to open files. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8929/open-data-file-from-cdfplayer if that is what you are trying to do. You'd need the pro CDF for that.

Comment: I don't know much about what is OK on the free CDFPlayer, but maybe `FileNames[{"*.nb"}` is disallowed because it looks as if you were fishing for what files are available. Try `Button["open", Print @ RandomChoice[FileNames[{"*.nb"}, {NotebookDirectory[ButtonNotebook[]]}]]]`. It might give you more insight.

Comment: Thanks for those comments, and that information.   It makes sense that CDFPlayer would not be able to "fish" for file names and open one.  I'd still like to find a solution that would choose a question at random, but I can simply link to the files.  So my question is answered….

Answer (score 1):

HI…  I found I could get this to work using a SUPPLIED list of questions.   I WILL know ahead of time how many questions there are,  so I didn't need to "fish" for the file names.

I just put the questions in a folder with nice sequential names,  Q1, Q2, Q3, etc. and used the following
(which works fine in the free CDFPlayer)

```
Button["open",
 NotebookOpen[
  FileNameJoin[{
    NotebookDirectory[EvaluationNotebook[]],
    "Data",
    "Questions",
    RandomChoice["Q " <> ToString[#] <> ".nb" & /@ Range[3]]}]]]
```